# How to encode the inputstream from microphone using Media​Devices​ API/Java to mp3 without using NodeJs

Tags: javascript, java, encoding, content-type, audio-recording

I am trying to work with the Google Cloud Speech API to transcribe the audio to text. I have a working prototype where I have a mp3/wav (prerecorded) file that is correct and accepted by the API to do the request when it is sent as base64 format. However the problem I am having now is, that in an other prototype where I capture the sound from the user (client-side) and save it as mp3/wav, the base64 doesn't correspond with the file-type (it sees it as video/webm instead of audio/mp3 / audio/x-wav).

Sidenote: The audio recordings are fine and playable.

Tried saving the blob file as mp3
Tried recorder.js

```
const mime = ['audio/wav', 'audio/mpeg', 'audio/webm', 'audio/ogg']
        .filter(MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported)[0];
        const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(mediaStreamObj, {
        mimeType: mime
    });
//the stop event
mediaRecorder.onstop = (ev)=>{
            let blob = new Blob(chunks, { type : 'audio/mp3;' });
            chunks = [];
            let audioURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            audioSave.src = audioURL;
```

}

I expect to have a file with the filetype/mimetype audio/mp3 and not video/webm